# ASP.NET MVC 5-Best approach to load user data when page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building user portal and wants to load authenitcated user data from database when form authentication happens.
Can you please help me to understand what are best approach asp.net mvc have to load the user data from database when page load post the form authentication

One I can think of is JQUERY to query data from database using CONTROLLER

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Microsoft's tutorials first, you can get started [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security). Follow these tutorials first before asking questions here.

Once you understand the concepts, I suggest you use the ASP.NET Identity framework to authenticate and authorize your users. It provides many out of the box features and allows customization according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use what the ASP.Net MVC plumbing offers.

Specifically, use the `UserManager<T>` in namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`(maybe start [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity))

However, if this is your first time, in order to get you started, I would recommend you try to create a new MVC sample application instead of writing an application from an empty template: it will help you understand the mechanisms ASP.Net MVC exposes for your need.

Good luck :)